# Purging storyboards in the background iOS app

Tags: ios, storyboard

I'm experiencing an issue when navigating to a second viewcontroller, the original root of the storyboard is not purged and remains visible when transitioning between the screens. The original root screen is not shown when navigating back, only when navigating to the second viewcontroller. See attached screenshot for explanation of the flow.

[image: image explaining the flow]

Any suggestions on how I can avoid having unwanted storyboards haunting in the background?

Comment: please provide the screenshot as a link, an admin will edit the question to include the actual image.

Comment: Are you adding the views to the window directly? You only need to specify the `rootViewController` to the window, but it seems that you are adding the view to the window.

Comment: We are not using the rootViewController, it is a story board with the above flow described in the image.